# Linking to generated Java protobuf code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

Here's the workflow that I'm trying to build

- compile my proto files using a script, putting the generated src in a specified directory
- link to the generated classes in Eclipse
- compile my project

I am easily able to do this for C++ using Eclipse CDT: In my project I choose File->New->Other and choose File under General. Then I click on Advanced and select link to system file.

I haven't discovered how to do this for Java, though. Once answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192596/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-resolve-classes-generated-with-maven-) suggests creating another project with the generated code and make that a dependency to my project. This works but seems redundant.

Is there a way to directly link the generated protobuf Java classes to my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Java doesn't really have a "link" phase. Your two options are really:

- Build the generated code outside Eclipse, and then add a reference to the relevant directory or jar file
- Include the generated code within Eclipse (e.g. by having a source path which includes the directory containing your generated code) and get Eclipse to build it along with the rest of your code.

I suspect that the first option will make it easier to keep the generated code well away from your real source, but the second option *may* make it easier to browse the generated source, and package everything up.

Comment: Thanks for teh answer! I think the 2nd solution sounds better. However, when I try to include the source directory from Properties->Java Build Path, under Source Eclipse doesn't let me link to an arbitrary system file. Does the generated code directory *has* to be placed under the project directory?

Comment: @recipriversexclusion: I can't remember whether there's any way of including an external directory... I don't think I've ever needed to. That's why I said that the first option would make it easier to keep the generated source away from your project :)

Comment: You might want to try the 'link source' button on the build path source tab.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is it still true?

Comment: @Gibbs: I haven't been in the Java world for a while - I don't know what the best practices are now.