# M2E and having maven generated source folders as eclipse source folders

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a maven project in eclipse and have maven goals that run annotation processors to generate code. The output folder for this code is `target/generated-sources/apt`.

In order for Eclipse to see this generated code I need to add `target/generated-sources/apt` as a source folder to the Eclipse project.

However, this causes there to be an error of type "Maven Configuration Problem" saying

> Project configuration is not up-to-date with `pom.xml`. Run project
> configuration update

I think I understand why this is the case as Eclipse has a different set of source folders to Maven's set. But I need this different set, as I need Eclipse to be able to see the `generated` source folders...

When doing a pure Maven built, these source folders will be included in the build, by Maven.

BTW, I have upgraded to the official Eclipse release of the Maven Eclipse plugin, m2e 1.0 - what used to be m2eclipse. I'd like to see if I can find a work around/solution to this with the m2e plugin before I have to go back to the old m2eclipse version.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to attach the source directory with the [build-helper-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin).

Like so:

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

You will also need to:

- Install the "Apt M2E Connector" from the Eclipse Marketplace.
  To do so click the error in the Overview tab of your pom.xml and select "Discover".
- Ensure there are no plugin execution filters for the build-helper-maven-plugin (see https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)

Comment: this solution works great when the `m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin` is installed in Eclipse

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Can you elaborate on the build-helper-plugin setup?

Comment: <plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>add-source</id>
   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>add-source</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <sources>
     <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
     <source>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsimport/java</source>
    </sources>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>

Comment: Perhaps I need to install that m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin, which I found no obvious way to do. Can anyone point me at installation instructions for that connector?

Comment: Yes, you will need that. It's available on the m2eclipse market place. Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Okay, worked for me now. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: just a note for others (like me), `plugin` element is in `/project/build/plugins` and NOT in `/project/build/pluginManagement/plugins`

Comment: With Kepler, I had to also install m2e connector for build helper maven plugin. (Just open your pom inside the maven pom editor of eclipse and click on the red link at the top).

Comment: The Apt M2E Connector is not required, but the org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecyclemapping.buildhelper.xml plugin, available via Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery. If "Open Catalog" fails, go to the URL in a browser, download the JAR, open it and copy the lifeCycleMappingMetaData as part of your pluginManaagement in your pom.xml.

Comment: Now I am being told that I have a duplicate class (by the maven-compiler-plugin) since the class is already being compiled by the maven-jaxb-plugin, which generated java classed based on an xsd file representing XML configuration structure.

Comment: Tell XJC not to compile the code but generate only.

Comment: Repository of "Apt M2E Connector" does not exists anymore. Alternatives?

Comment: Same. the link to build-helper-maven is broken. It maybe should be replaced by this [one](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: As far as I can tell, as of `build-helper-maven-plugin` with `<version>` specified as `3.2.0` (the latest as of writing), there is no need to use Apt M2E Connector. Currently working on Eclipse IDE 2020-06, using embedded Maven 3.6.3 in Eclipse, and our problems with source folder having exclusions (\*\*) went away after attempting to add the source folders' directory paths in. Now, the inclusions all have (\*\*/\*.java) in them.

Answer (score 80):

Right-click the Error message:

> Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml Run project
>   configuration update

in the Problems View and select *Quick Fix* and click *Finish* to select the default *Update project configuration*. This fixes it.

Comment: This works for me too. Why isn't this the accepted answer? Seems the accepted answer does too much.

Comment: @NielsBasjes this isn't the accepted answer because it simply isn't helpful.  When you add something to the build path in Eclipse, that means you are no longer in sync with the POM, hence the warning.  Updating the project configuration simply removes the extra build path entry, which was the initial problem to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

After switching to new versions of m2e/maven/apt,... i had builderrors because of the duplicated files, caused by the added buildpath by the buildhelper, so i needed to remove the "apt-generated"-Folders from the buildhelper.

To fix the Problem in Eclipse, not adding the "apt-generated"-folder via Update Maven Configuration in M2E, i've written a M2E Plugin to fix this problem. It adds the outputDirectories configured in the maven-apt-plugin to the buildpath of the Project.

https://apt-m2e.googlecode.com

Comment: unfortunately @Stefan Wo your plugin page/repo is now 404 at googlecode.com; would you mind updating it, as well as the Eclipse Marketplace entry? see https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apt-m2e-connector

Answer (score 3):

In m2e 1.0 the handling of Maven plugins has changed. You might be lacking a specific m2e extension for your code generating plugin. Here is all the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-extension-development.html) I managed to find.

This [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349935) may also be relevant.

Comment: i guess m2e is new and has lots of outstanding development

Comment: I believe the problem is that just applying Maven plugins to m2eclipse projects, as m2eclipse used to do, just happened to work most of the time, but wasn't guaranteed to always do the right thing. The new approach is potentially more solid, but requires that many Maven plugins have an m2e counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350081

request on CXF JIRA (see [1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4152)) to add lifecycle mappings in the cxf-codegen-plugin itself. This would require m2e 1.1 but I believe it is better approach than having connectors built outside of cxf project, assuming that lifecycle mapping API would change less frequently than cxf-codegen-plugin and cxf.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the buildhelper m2e connector available in the discovery catalog. I'm using Eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 1

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.0

mvn clean install
```

work perfectly.

But in eclipse I have the same error on Asinc class.

Just press F5 on project. Fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I found that worked good using spring 3.1.1 which does have the 3.0.6 version as well in it.  Once I got the plugins setup and put into the correct area of the pom and included the argline and endorseddirs to have the java sources put out into the target/generated-sources/cxf folder then maven generated the sources ok.

....

```
 <properties>...

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>.....
   </dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>....

</dependencies>



<!-- *************************** Build process ************************************* -->
<build>
    <finalName>eSurety</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Force Java 6 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Deployent on AS from console
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.as.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
        -->

        <!-- wildbill added tomcat plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>              
        </plugin>

        <!-- Surefire plugin before 2.9 version is buggy. No need to declare here,
              it's being referenced below w/ the version
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
        -->

        <!-- developer added these -->   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>target/generated-sources/cxf</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>target/generated-sources/cxf</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>                       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>                       
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/cxf</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>                      
        </plugin>                                                 
    </plugins>
</build>



<!-- *********************** Profiles ************************************ -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be 
            used when invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization 
            your app will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 
            'deployments' folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>projName</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>                                                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>                        
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>                                                                                               
                            <configuration>
                                <fork>once</fork>
                                <additionalJvmArgs>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=target/generated-sources/cxf</additionalJvmArgs>                                          
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>                             
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>                       
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                           <version>2.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                           <version>2.2</version>
                        </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Actual war created in default target dir -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>                                               
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If your wsdl folder is in ${basedir}/src/main/resources it'll find it automatically

Hope this helps!
~wildbill

Answer (score 0):

In case for some reason you can't use the build helper plugin the easiest way (albeit not as convenient and somewhat tedious) I have found to deal with this is:

1. Separate the generated source code into its own project or sub module.
2. You will want to keep this project predominately closed or not imported into Eclipse when you are working on the parent project.
3. In the parent project that needs the generated code make sure to now depend on the generated source code project via Maven pom dependency.
4. When you need to update the generated code go to the generated code project and run `mvn install`. Now refresh the parent project by right clicking and selecting *Maven->Update Project...*

This generally works well for projects that use a semi static source for code generation such as SOAP WSDLs (Apache CXF) or code generated from a database (jOOQ). For APT and other AspectJ-like-code it doesn't work as well because you are editing the source frequently.

Answer (score 0):

For new visitors to this question -

build helper maven plugins and m2e connectors go hand in hand. Older versions
(before 2.0) of build helpers have moved into an eclipse archive link

[build helper versions archived](https://archive.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/)

Pick the correct link from the list and add it as an eclipse update site. It should ask you for a bunch (seriously.. a huge bunch ) of eclipse updates . Please accept and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

the configuration to the build helper plugin did work for us.

but be aware, that the destination folder always has to be equal to the configuration of the plugin u're using for the annotation processing itself.

for example the maven-processor-plugin uses the target folder ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt as default. if you wish another destination for your generated source files you can set it by the  tag as shown below.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <defaultOutputDirectory>apt_generated</defaultOutputDirectory>
                                <processors>
                                    <processor>com.any.processor.invoker</processor>
                                </processors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the solution

1. Open Marker View (Window > Show View
2. Right-click on the Error message
3. Select Quick Fix
4. Click Finish