# How do I resolve compilation errors that show up on classes but not projects in Eclipse when using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting compilation errors when I open a specific class file in Eclipse. However, the class doesn't show a compilation error icon in the Project Explorer. I have enabled dependency management by right-clicking the project and using the Maven menu.

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 and Maven 2.2.1.

[image: looks like this]

Comment: place a screenshot, that will be helpful for others

Comment: It looks like a form of this question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7160614/366695). Thanks Kevin Wong and Michael-O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen this problem before, but I'd try performing the obligatory clean and build all on the project. I suggest making sure the following options are checked in Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building:

- Scrub output folders when cleaning projects
- Rebuild class files modified by others

There are several good suggestions in the question [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7160614/366695) by `bdill`, specifically to try updating your project configuration from the pom.

Answer (score 1):

Use Package Explorer, not Project Explorer. It's a lot more reliable for Java projects.

Comment: Wasn't sure what people still used for side views. Thanks for the tip.