# unable to access generated sources in maven into classpath

Tags: maven, apache-axis

I am using axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin to generate stub classes for a wsdl file. These are all generated into generated-sources folder in target.Now i want to use those classes into my src/main/java .

So please give me useful information to resolve this issue in my project.

Thanks
Narsi

Comment: why do you want having the generated classes into src/main/java ?

Answer (score 2):

[I found a similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160006/m2e-and-having-maven-generated-source-folders-as-eclipse-source-folders)

Basically, you want to use the [Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add an additional source directory to your project.

Here's an example from the [usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>some directory</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated classes like in this case the source of those classes are the wsdl file(s) which would means that every time you run your build the generated classes will be overwritten in the src/main/java folder which means having changes to commit into your version control. 
That means never put generated code into src/main/java leave it as the defaults to **target/generated-sources/...*** Furthermore there is no need to put the generated classes into src/main/java.