# maven/apt generated classes in eclipse

Tags: maven, jpa

Using following configuration in master pom, some classes (metamodel FYI) are generated for all child projects having jpa entities under target/generated-sources, as expected.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This works perfectly from Maven and Netbeans.

Some team members still use Eclipse. There, generated classes aren't found automatically. They can be opened if added manually to the "build path" (whatever it means as this is redundant to pom.xml). However, that's not stable and will be reset whenever they "update the project" (shouldn't even be needed but...) to reflect project's maven configuration.

My question is, how to configure Eclipse to use this project's configuration automatically? I don't want to change the project's pom.xml too much, as they are perfectly legal and work well outside of Eclipse, which I just want to be taught to behave correctly.

UPDATE: M2Eclipse is installed and doesn't solve this, which is basically our problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160006/m2e-and-having-maven-generated-source-folders-as-eclipse-source-folders

Answer (score 0):

There ist a project/Eclipse-Plugin called M2Eclipse ([link](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)).

The plugin includes the following feature:

> Dependency management for Eclipse build path based on Maven's pom.xml

Comment: Already installed, which allows us to at least "import" those projects in Eclipse and configure *some* things. Doesn't help for this.