# Maven Not able to resolve dependencies for classes generated inside target/generated-sources/javacc folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am trying to set up my project in eclipse . One of the module references classes in the target/generatedsources folder. Unfortunately Eclipse is not able to resolve it . I even modified the pom.xml and followed the solution mentioned here

[M2E and having maven generated source folders as eclipse source folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160006/m2e-and-having-maven-generated-source-folders-as-eclipse-source-folders)   and also installed Apt-M2e but it didn't work . Although maven is able to build the source from command line but in Eclipse it is not able to resolve .

Even tried manually adding the path till the folder but it does not work . It shows empty packages and does not import class files whereas they are present in the target/generated-sources .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is, that the content is shown under "Referenced Libraries". You must revert that.

After that the little icon on the javacc folder (in the middle of your screenshot) must be gone.

Then, right-click on the javacc folder an select "build path" -> "use as source folder".

Let me know if that helped.