# How to make Eclipse recognize folders as "code folders" when a project is imported?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven Java project in which I added to the pom:

```
<build>
....
    <plugin>
                <!-- adding second test source directory (just for integration tests) -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</build>
```

InteliJ recognized my java and resource folders under integration-test as a code folder, but Eclipse doesn't.
Is there any way that eclipse adds these folders as code folders when the project is imported?

Comment: Did you install M2E plugin? Then use Configure->Convert to Maven Project. Then you need to add source dir `src/integration-test/java` to the Maven Compiler Plugin. In the default directory layout you would put your test code into `src/test/java` and it works out of the box

Comment: Yes, src/test works. I want to have both srC/test and src/intergation-tests

Comment: Usually unit tests and intergration tests are in the same source folder. Your problem is caused by the separation of both. I suggest not using your own directory layout with Maven since this will cause many problems and you always have to configure around it. Just stick to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on your folder in `Project Explorer` select `Build Path` option in context menu and later click `Use as Source Folder` in menu which appears after choosing `Build Path`.

Comment: Ok, but everyone that imports this project will have to do the same. I thught that Eclipse would be able to infer that from pom, just as InteliJ did. Is this possible?

Comment: Eclipse ignores test resources. As far as I know, you can't work around it using Maven, unless you also add it to resources available during compilation and runtime.

Comment: I am not sure but probably Eclipse cannot recognize folder named `integration-test`. If your folder will be named `test` Eclipse will automatically use it as source folder.

Comment: I have a test folder, they are for unit tests. My integration tests is for integration tests. So I can run unit tests on test phase and integration tests on IT phase.

Comment: Please look at `best answer` in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160006/m2e-and-having-maven-generated-source-folders-as-eclipse-source-folders)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using your own directory layout with Maven since this will cause many problems and you always have to configure around it. [Just stick to the standard.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html)

- Separate integration tests and unit tests not by their source folders, but by their name.
- Put all tests in `src/test/java`. You don't have to configure anything at this point, this path is taken by default.
- Call integration tests `IT*.java` and unit tests `UT*.java`.
- They can be run separately because `maven-surefire-plugin` executes unit tests and `maven-failsafe-plugin` executed integration tests. You can define filename patterns for identifying the test classes.
- You could also create profiles for running only UTs or only ITs.

  ```
  <project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/UT*.java</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/IT*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Further reading: http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2013/01/running-unit-tests-integration-tests-separately-maven-testng/

There is also a interesting article about the correct usage of integration tests here: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-correct-way-to-use-integration-tests-in-your-build-process/

Comment: Ok, that seems interesting, but would I be able to run all my unit tests easily without running the ITs? (From the IDe, while developing)

Comment: You could run the tests with Maven, since it is your build system or create test suites: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm