# Is it possible to use the openapi-generator maven plugin to create a Java client in an existing maven project?

Tags: java, openapi-generator

All the examples I can find (and when trying to use this I find the same output) approach generation of a Java API client from a given spec as creating an entirely separate Maven module/project as the output. I'd like to generate the sources *within* my existing project structure. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [this example](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/), I think there should be no problem in pasting the code in your project's pom.xml. I would generate the output in some other location though, for example under `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/...something`:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
  ...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <configOptions>
                   <sourceFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</sourceFolder>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you would have to attach the generated source as input for your maven project.:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
  ...

<!-- Attaching source directories (for Eclipse to create the source folders properly).
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160006/m2e-and-having-maven-generated-source-folders-as-eclipse-source-folders
        -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
```